# How can I add an icon to an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Will simply putting an image into the project folder do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create your image sized 57x57 pixels (for iPhone).
2. Name it **Icon.png** (you can change this name in Info.plist)
3. Add it to the Resources folder in Xcode.

That should get you started and there are [more details here.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW16)  You may also want to add a smaller icon for the Settings app (29x29 called **Icon-settings.png**).

Comment: The "more details here" link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

[Apple iPhone Human Interface Guidelines:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

> Name your icon file Icon.png and place
>   it at the top level of your
>   application bundle.